# BG image from web works but folder image doesn't

Tags: css

I'm taking a course on Udemy and I've followed what it shows in the lesson and even asked in discord but haven't received a solution.

The background image I used from the web using a image URL works, but when I try to link an image saved on the same folder as the CSS and HTML files nothing happens. All I get is a blank white background instead of an image. I'll be adding screenshots.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQJLF.jpg

```css
body {
    background-image: url(starwars.jpg);
    background-size: auto;
}

h2 {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    border: 5px solid purple;
    cursor: crosshair;
}

p {
    color: pink;
}
p {
    color: green;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: write some code here dont put image urls

Comment: We have a nice snippet formatting - and we require minimal convenience for answerers :)  use `edit` below your question an put code as a snippet, please

Comment: Is that the code snippet you were asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try `background-image: url('starwars.jpg');`

Answer (score 0):

Check the file path for the image and make sure it reflects what is being written in your `url()` css.  Right now you are showing that image is located in the root directory of your project. If the image is not in the root directory, say for example it's in a folder called "images" in your root, then the url should read `url('images/starwars.jpg')`.

It would be good practice to put any image you want to use in your site in a folder named "images" inside your root directory anyway.  Try that, and see if it works.

So just to clarify: create a new folder inside the root folder of your project.  It should be on the same hierarchical level as your `index.html` file.  Take the image, where ever it is, and place it inside that new images folder.  Change your css to say

```
background-image: url('images/starwars.jpg');
```